# With Leiningen, how do I install documentation?

Tags: eclipse, clojure, leiningen, counterclockwise

I forked a library on github [(seesaw)](https://github.com/daveray/seesaw) and ran "lein install" which made it available as a dependency in my local maven repo.  But when I include it as a dependency in my other project, my IDE (eclipse's counterclockwise) can't find the documentation.  I think this has to do with the way I installed the dependency rather than the way I imported it in my own project because usually when I depend on dependencies, I can see the documentation.

I think the equivalent maven command is "site".  But when I type "lein help", I don't see anything related to documentation.

Comment: Deleted  my  answer.   See  this  instead: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5334525/state-of-the-art-for-clojure-documentation-tools